# Locating roots of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a,b,c$ be real numbers. $a>0$, $|c|>1$, and $b^2-2ac >0 $. Find the number of roots of the function $f(z) =az^2+bz+c-e^{-z}$ in the region $\{z : Re(z)\geq 0\}$ for every $a,b,c$. When will it have one real root on the real axis?

I have tried using Rouche's theorem in a semicircunference with center $0$ and radius R, but I didn't get any results. I also tried studying the roots of $g(z) =p(z)p(\overline{z})-e^{-z}$ where $p(z)=az^2+bz+c$ using again Rouche's theorem and I got to some results but I didn't really know how to link them with the roots of f. I would like to know how to aproach this problem.

Comment: do you really mean $b^2-2ac$ and not $b^2-4ac$ ?

Comment: yes, it was the text of an exercice we had to do and I had no idea how. When I did $p(iy)p(-iy)$ that inequality comes in handy, but I dont know if there would be any other way to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(z) = az^2+bz+c$. For $z=iy$ with $y \in \Bbb R$  we have
$$
 |p(z)|^2 = |(c-ay^2) + iby|^2 = (c-ay^2)^2 + b^2y^2 \\
= c^2 + (b^2-2ac)y^2 + a^2y^4 \ge c^2 > 1
$$
and therefore
$$
 |f(z) - p(z)| = |e^{-z}| = 1 < |p(z)| \, .
$$
Also
$$
 |f(z) - p(z)| = |e^{-z}| \le 1 < |p(z)| \, .
$$
if $|z| = R$ is sufficiently large. So Rouché's theorem shows that $f$ and $p$ have the same number of zeros in the right half-plane (which can be zero, one, or two).