# Show that $g(z)=(z-2i)^2-4e^{iz}$ has two zeros in the upper half complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Just finished my exam in Complex Analysis and while I know that they wanted me to do, I just can't find the right function to compare with.

I have shown previous to this that $g$ only has simple zeros and now I have to prove that $g(z)$ has exactly two zeros in $\{w\in\mathbb{C}\vert \text{Im}(w)>0\}$. One of the hints tells us to look at the simple curve that runs from $[-R,R]$ and then in a semicircle with $Re^{it}$ with $t\in[0,\pi]$ and use Rouche's theorem.

I know that the function should have two simple zeros, since $g(z)$ only has simple zeros. I thought of a function like $f(z)=(z-i)(z-2i)$ because it has two zeros in the upper half plane, but I just never moved on from here.

What to do?

Comment: But the exam is finished you claim, yes?  Do what do you mean when asking "what to do?"

Comment: @amWhy Lmao why is it so wrong to wanna know how to solve a problem just because the exam is finished? If I fail I'll have to do it over

Comment: https://ibb.co/DM6kYyk
Feel free to translate

Comment: This looks like an application of Rouché's theorem. If you rotate the upper half plane to the right half plane then you can probably proceed similarly as here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4000997/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is not that hard once you notice that $|e^{iz}|<1$ in the upper half-plane so this means that all zeroes of $g$ in the upper plane must be inside the disc $|z-2i| < 2$, while on the circle $C:|z-2i|=2$, the only possible solution would be at $z=0$ which doesn't work since $g(0)=-8$

But then considering $f(z)=(z-2i)^2$ we have that $|f|=2$ on the circle $C$, while for $t \ge 0$ we have that $tf+g=(t+1)(z-2i)^2-4e^{iz}$ doesn't vanish on the circle either as for $t>0, |(t+1)(z-2i)^2|=4(t+1)>4 \ge |4e^{iz}|$ and $t=0$ is the case above ($g$ doesn't vanish on the circle).

Then by Rouche (or just noticing that $\lambda g +(1-\lambda)f, 0 \le \lambda \le 1$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$ that doesn't vanish on the circle $C$ by the above), it follows that $f,g$ have the same number of zeroes inside the disc and that is clearly $2$, so we are done!

Comment: Doesn't f(z) only have one root?

Comment: $2i$ is a double root of $f$ so it has two roots

Comment: I thought counted with multiplicity meant that they had to same amount of roots and their multiplicities had to match too... Thanks for the answer and the explanation!

Comment: Rouche just claims that the number of roots (counted as usual) is the same, but multiplicities can be different (think of a small perturbation of $z^2$ to $z^2+\epsilon$ where you apply Rouche on a disc of radius $1$; happy to be of help